# Pass by reference as rvalue

Tags: c++, pass-by-rvalue-reference

When I try to call the *move* member as pass by reference, the compiler throws an error but when I redefine the member function to pass by value, it works.

Can I not use pass by reference as an rvalue in my member function?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Screen{
private:
    std::string contents;
    using position = std::string::size_type;
    position height,width,cursor_position;
public:
    Screen() = default;
    Screen& move(position&,position&); // Pass by reference
};

Screen& Screen::move(position& row,position& col)
{
    (*this).cursor_position = (row * width) + col;
    return *this;
}

int main() {
    Screen myScreen;
    myScreen.move(4,0); // This line gives a compile error
}
```

Comment: What language is this?  What does the version of the code that doesn't work look like?  What does it mean to "call a member as pass by reference"?

Comment: You shouldn't accept parameters by non-const reference unless the function intends to modify the parameter

Answer (score 5):

No, rvalue cannot be passed as non-const lvalue reference. It can be passed as const lvalue reference though because the compiler will create a temporary to point the lvalue to.

Answer (score 1):

```
int main() {
    Screen myScreen;
    position rowTmp = 4;
    position colTmp = 0;
    myScreen.move(rowTmp,colTmp); 
}
```

Try it!

You need to create two real variables for 'Pass by refrrence'.

Comment: Please add some explanation to help the questioner; your code does seem to fix his problem, but on its own it is not really useful.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.@ Ken Y-N.I will pay attention to this issue in  the future.